# Dart Mirror API: Getting the result of a reflection call

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Having mirrors returning futures dramatically limits what you can do with them.

For example,

```dart
class ObjectA {
  methodA(){}
  methodB(){}
}

class DynamicWrapper extends MagicalDynamicWrapper {
  ObjectA real;
  Map<String, Function> methods;
  DynamicWrapper(this.real, this.methods);
}

var w = new DynamicWrapper(new ObjectA(), {"methodB" : (){ 'do something' }});
w.methodA() // calls ObjectA.methodA
w.methodB() // calls 'do something'
```

The way I'd normally do it is by defining noSuchMethod in MagicalDynamicWrapper:

- that will check if there is a method with such a name in the methods map, then call it.
- and if there is none, it will call the "real" object via reflection.

Unfortunately, calling the real object will always return a future. So it doesn't work.

At some point it was possible to get the value of a Future (using the value getter), but that getter is no longer available.

My Question:

Is there a way to get the result of a reflection call synchronously?

In a distributed setting futures are definitely the way to go. But in a non-distributed setting, where all the meta information is available, it should be possible to get the value of a reflection call. I'd make a huge difference for the authors of testing frameworks and build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having mirrors returning futures certainly makes sense

No it doesn't (well, at least not to me :-) ). And it will probably be changed, see http://dartbug.com/4633#c17

> The way I'd normally do it is by defining noSuchMethod in MagicalDynamicWrapper that will check if there is a method with such a name in the methods map, then call it, and if there is none, it will call the "real" object via reflection.

Check the `InvocationMirror` documentation. You can forward method calls using the `invokeOn` method:

```dart
class Proxy {
  var target;
  Map<String, Function> overrides;

  Proxy(this.target, this.overrides);

  noSuchMethod(invocation) {
    if (overrides.containsKey(invocation.memberName)) {
      return overrides[invocation.memberName]();
    } else {
      return invocation.invokeOn(target);
    }
  }
}
```

> Is there a way to get the result of a reflection call synchronously?

No, it isn't. Not right now. You can star http://dartbug.com/4633 if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
The invokeOn method works in my case.
I hope that the sync reflection API will be added soon. 
Cause pretty much every interesting library I think of writing requires it.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being you can use deprecatedFutureValue(aFuture). Obviously by the name they're discouraging use of it and it will eventually go away, but I agree that until we get a synchronous mirrors API you absolutely need something like this.